# При запуске проекта yii2-advance в логах nginx выпадают ошибки ядра, в чем может быть проблема?

Tags: php, yii2, nginx

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument
>   supplied for foreach() in
>   /var/www/yii/crmtest/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseArrayHelper.php
>   on line 123 PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The "id" configuration
>   for the Application is required.' in
>   /var/www/yii/crmtest/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php:219
>   Stack trace:
>   0 /var/www/yii/crmtest/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(201): yii\base\Application->preInit(Array)
>   1 /var/www/yii/crmtest/frontend/web/index.php(17): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
>   2 {main}   thrown in /var/www/yii/crmtest/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php on line
>   219" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1,
>   server: mysite.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1"

Конфиг nginx etc/nginx/site-available

```
server {
charset utf-8;
client_max_body_size 128M;

listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
#listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## слушаем ipv6

server_name mysite.test;
#root /var/www/yii/crm_2.3/backend/web;
root /var/www/yii/crm_2.3/frontend/web;
#root /var/www/yii/crm/backend/web;
index index.php;

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

location / {
# Перенаправляем все запросы к несуществующим директориям и файлам на index.php
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# раскомментируйте строки ниже во избежание обработки Yii обращений к несуществующим статическим файлам
location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
try_files $uri =404;
access_log off;
log_not_found off;
expires off;
}
#error_page 404 /404.html;

location ~ \.php$ {
include fastcgi_params;
#fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;

fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
}

location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
access_log off;
log_not_found off;
deny all;
}
}
```

Comment: а в конфиге yii2 `frontend/config/main.php` id указан?

Comment: @pa3py6aka return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
 'modules' => [

Comment: ну ошибку выдаёт будто id не указан, сам файл `/var/www/yii/crm_2.3/frontend/web/index.php` не меняли? Там конфиг подключается, проверьте пути до файлов конфигурации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы даже сказал, что это не ошибки ядра, а ошибки взаимодействия nginx и fpm.
Необходимо правильно настроить конфиги nginx и php и перегрузить эти сервисы.

В конфигах виртуального хоста надо найти что-то типа `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;` (это настройка через порт), а в конфиге `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` (в зависимости от версии пхп) `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`

Для настройки сокетов аналогично должно быть. Или можно настроить на порты. Вот тут один из вариантов [настройки виртуального хоста nginx и диагностика ошибок](http://www.masterwebs.ru/topic/29139-lp-nastroika-virtualnih-hostov-v-nginx/). Главное не забыть сделать рестарт, релоад не поможет.

Comment: Я настроил для fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock; по примерам. что для php7.0 когда стояла , что для 5.6 которая сейчас стоит. Все равно не работает. В теле вопроса приведу конфиг nginx. Файл по данному пути стоит.

Comment: Надо испробовать старинный метод, чтобы локализовать ошибку. Если в индексном файле exit('ok'); отрабатывает без проблем, значит nginx+fpm работают и следует искать ошибку в файлах проекта.

Comment: В итоге я поставил apache2 настроил , сайт запустился, в какой то момент такая же ошибка вышла ,что вместо сайта отображается только текст, в самом etc/php/php5.6/apache2 в конфи я до этого клал файл php.ini чтобы увеличить объем загружаемого файла бд для phpmyadmin. Я подумал может дело в файле php.ini который я в конфиг положил ,удалил его и сайт опять начал работать нормально. ( основной файл php.ini который лежит в папке cli при изменение объема данных для загрузки файлов в phpmyadmin не реагировал) Я где то еще ковырялся в итоге когда я отключил апач , сайт уже работал на nginx ....